# how to break down following array using foreach in cakephp?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to break down the below array using `foreach` loop.

```
     "childs": {
          "bars-pubs": {
               "id": "7",
               "parent": "1",
               "name": "Bars & Pubs",
               "display_name": "Bars & Pubs",
               "alias": "bars-pubs",
               "image": null
          },
          "billards-bars": {
            "id": "8",
            "parent": "1",
            "name": "Billards Bars",
            "display_name": "Billards Bars",
            "alias": "billards-bars",
            "image": null
          },
          "bowling-allies": {
            "id": "9",
            "parent": "1",
            "name": "Bowling Allies",
            "display_name": "Bowling Allies",
            "alias": "bowling-allies",
            "image": null
          },
          "cigar-bar": {
             "id": "10",
             "parent": "1",
             "name": "Cigar Bar",
             "display_name": "Cigar Bar",
             "alias": "cigar-bar",
             "image": null
          },
      },
```

In the above array if i break down the code using `foreach` loop it always gives me first array under childs.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? By using the `break` keyword in a loop, you will discontinue the loops execution, which is why you are only retrieving the first array. Please clarify want you want to achieve with this array

Answer (score 1):

```
$yourArray = array(
            "childs"=>array(
                            ...
                      )
            );

foreach($yourArray["childs"] as $child) {
    debug($child);
}
```